# OAuth2.0 authorization code flow in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0

I wrote the below function to pop up an IE window to handle the user authentication of the OAuth2.0 authorization code flow in PowerShell which works but when calling it as a function, it doesn't stay in the while loop to wait for the URL of the IE window to change and to filter out the OAuth2.0 authorization code and then close the window.

Is there a way to keep the function "open" for longer and to make sure it waits for the URL of the IE window to change?

*All remarks regarding the function are welcome...*

```
function Show-OAuth2AuthCodeWindow {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, HelpMessage = "The OAuth2 authorization code URL pointing towards the oauth2/v2.0/authorize endpoint as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow")]
    [System.Uri] $URL
  )
  try {

    # create an Internet Explorer object to display the OAuth 2 authorization code browser window to authenticate
    $InternetExplorer = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
    $InternetExplorer.Width = "600"
    $InternetExplorer.Height = "500"
    $InternetExplorer.AddressBar = $false # disable the address bar
    $InternetExplorer.ToolBar = $false # disable the tool bar
    $InternetExplorer.StatusBar = $false # disable the status bar

    # store the Console Window Handle (HWND) of the created Internet Explorer object
    $InternetExplorerHWND = $InternetExplorer.HWND

    # make the browser window visible and navigate to the OAuth2 authorization code URL supplied in the $URL parameter
    $InternetExplorer.Navigate($URL)

    # give Internet Explorer some time to start up
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    # get the Internet Explorer window as application object
    $InternetExplorerWindow = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows() | Where-Object {($_.LocationURL -match "(^https?://.+)") -and ($_.HWND -eq $InternetExplorerHWND)}

    # wait for the URL of the Internet Explorer window to hold the OAuth2 authorization code after a successful authentication and close the window
    while (($InternetExplorerWindow = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows() | Where-Object {($_.LocationURL -match "(^https?://.+)") -and ($_.HWND -eq $InternetExplorerHWND)})) {
      Write-Host $InternetExplorerWindow.LocationURL
      if (($InternetExplorerWindow.LocationURL).StartsWith($RedirectURI.ToString() + "?code=")) {
        $OAuth2AuthCode = $InternetExplorerWindow.LocationURL
        $OAuth2AuthCode = $OAuth2AuthCode -replace (".*code=") -replace ("&.*")
        $InternetExplorerWindow.Quit()
      }
    }

    # return the OAuth2 Authorization Code
    return $OAuth2AuthCode

  }
  catch {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Could not create a browser window for the OAuth2 authentication"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is `$RedirectURI` not defined in this function?

Comment: Is it a requirement to automate IE? You only really need it, if you have to manipulate the result of a rendered website (e. g. the website after it has been altered by JavaScript). If this is not needed, I recommend working with `Invoke-WebRequest`/`Invoke-RestMethod`, as they are reliable cmdlets. Using IE, you cannot wait reliably, as it is not defined when a website is fully loaded.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I'm writing this for PowerShell so the redirect URI is the default one for a native client (it's hard-coded earlier)

Comment: @Thomas unfortunately, the authorization code flow requires that a user interactively authenticates (at least once) so I'm afraid I don't have any other option than trying to automate it this way

Comment: @Glenn `$RedirectURI` is not an automatic variable so use it as a parameter when calling the function. My assumption is that Theo and AdminOfThings are right. Try writing `$RedirectURI` in the function and see what it returns

Comment: @Glenn Can the interaction be reduced to `Get-Credential`?

Comment: As stated in my earlier comment, the $RedirectURI variable is set earlier in the script...

Answer (score 1):

**Answer from this [blog post](https://medium.com/@sachin.hebballi/auth-code-flow-using-powershell-c8dacf460409)**

I managed to get the Auth code flow working using the headless chrome. All you need are these two components.

- [Chrome/edge driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver)
- [Selenium driver](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

Once you have these setup, you need to use the below Powershell commands to generate token using Auth code flow

```
$SeleniumWebDriverFullPath = ".\WebDriver.dll" # Full path to selenium web driver
$ClientId = ""
$Scopes = ""
$RedirectUri = ""

$authCodeUri = "$($AuthorizeEndpoint.TrimEnd("/"))?client_id=$ClientId&scope=$Scopes&redirect_uri=$RedirectUri&response_type=code

Write-Host $authCodeUri

Import-Module $SeleniumWebDriverFullPath
$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions
$ChromeOptions.AddArgument('headless')
$ChromeOptions.AcceptInsecureCertificates = $True

$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver($ChromeOptions);
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl($authCodeUri);

while (!$ChromeDriver.Url.Contains("code")) { Start-Sleep 1 }

Write-Host $ChromeDriver.Url

$ParsedQueryString = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($ChromeDriver.Url)
$Code = $ParsedQueryString[0]

Write-Host "Received code: $Code"
Write-Host "Exchanging code for a token"

$tokenrequest = @{ "client_id" = $ClientId; "grant_type" = "authorization_code"; "redirect_uri" = $RedirectUri; "code" = $ParsedQueryString[0] }
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $AuthTokenEndpoint -Body $tokenrequest

$tokenString = $token | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Thank you Sachin, the goal was however to keep the dependencies on a Windows 10 machine to a bare minimum (i.e.: none).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the function has no idea what `$RedirectURI` is.

You should make that a second parameter to the function or it should be (at least) [Script scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7#scope-modifiers)

I'd prefer using a second parameter, but if you do scoping, you should be able to use it inside the function with `$script:RedirectURI`

Comment: As already stated above, since I'm writing this for PowerShell, the redirect URI is the default one for a native client and is hard-coded earlier

Comment: @Glenn yes, but the variable hardcoded **outside** the function has no meaning **inside** the function. Using a simple `Write-Host $RedirectURI.ToString()` in the function would reveal that. Please adjust your function and add a second parameter to it. Then call the function using both `$URL` and `RedirectURI`

Comment: @Theo "variable hardcoded outside the function has no meaning inside the function". I wouldn't say that. If you define that variable before the function definition, it works well: `$a='bar';function foo {$a};foo` prints `bar`. Even `function foo {$a};$a='bar';foo` prints `bar`, where I would have some concerns.

Comment: @Thomas That depends. The OP is only showing us his/her function, nothing else. `$RedirectURI` may have been altered/cleared  between hardcoding it and calling the function. We also do not know if the function is in another script or module and how this is used in the script..

Comment: @Theo you are focusing on the $RedirectURI variable while I already assured you that it is set prior to the function and available within the function.

Comment: @Glenn I had no idea this question was still alive after more than a year..

Answer (score 0):

The following example does what you want with a WebBrowser control, which allows you to register a Navigating event handler to catch the authorization code obtained from your authorization server.

[PowerShell OAuth2 client](https://github.com/globalsign/OAuth-2.0-client-examples/blob/master/PowerShell/Powershell-example.ps1)

Comment: The link is now a 404 error.